# How can I send multiple selected items to server?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview

So I collection view that allows users to select multiple categories to feature their photo. When I select a cell the print statements work fine, it prints the name of the cells childValue as expected. When I go to submit the post, it only uploads to the last selected index to the database.

An example of the issue - If I select the categories "prints" and "green" the photo will only post "green" because it was the last selected index. How can I save all of the selections users make and send the post to the selected childValues?

```swift
    var selectedCategoryValue = ""

    var trend: Trend!
    var style: Style!

    // When a cell is selected, the postID will be added to the correct childvalue that is relevent to the post
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if collectionView == trendCollectionView {


        switch selectedSegmentIndex {

        case 0: self.trend = femaleTrends[indexPath.row]
        print("You selected row \(trend.childValue)")


        self.selectedCategoryValue = trend.childValue


        case 1: self.trend = maleTrends[indexPath.row]
            print("You selected row \(trend.childValue)")
            self.selectedCategoryValue = trend.childValue

             default: break

        }


        } else {

          // Once I figure out how to store multiple selected values, I will complete else statement
            switch selectedSegmentIndex {

            case 0: self.style = femaleStyles[indexPath.row]
            case 1: self.style = maleStyles[indexPath.row]

                 default: break

            }


        }


    }
```

Here is the function used when submit is pressed and the photo is uploaded to server

```swift
    func uploadPostToCategory(withPostId postId: String) {

        let selectedValue = [postId: 1]
            switch trend.gender {
            case .female:
                // add postId to childValue based on cell selection
                FEMALE_TRENDS_REF.child(selectedCategoryValue).updateChildValues(selectedValue)

            case.male:
                MALE_TRENDS_REF.child(selectedCategoryValue).updateChildValues(selectedValue)

            }



        }
```

handled `isSelected` inside the collection view cell here.

```swift
   override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet{
            if self.isSelected {
                trendCheckmark.isHidden = false

            }
            else {
                trendCheckmark.isHidden = true

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are just changing the variable `selectedCategoryValue` upon cell selection and making this an array that is appended to.

So:

`var selectedCategoryValues = [String]()`

then when one is selected:

`self.selectedCategoryValues.append(trend.childValue)`

and in your `uploadPostToCategory` function you will need a for loop to loop over all of the `selectedCategoryValue`'s like so:

```
func uploadPostToCategory(withPostId postId: String) {
    for selectedCategoryValue in selectedCategoryValues {
    let selectedValue = [postId: 1]
        switch trend.gender {
        case .female:
            // add postId to childValue based on cell selection
            FEMALE_TRENDS_REF.child(selectedCategoryValue).updateChildValues(selectedValue)

        case.male:
            MALE_TRENDS_REF.child(selectedCategoryValue).updateChildValues(selectedValue)

        }
       }

    }
```

you could also look into: `self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems`

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much for the education as well! Happy Coding

Comment: Sure! I would take a look at my suggested path of using indexPathsForSelected items if you want the user to be able to deselect items as well.

Comment: Yes I definitely will, that is much needed.